# iOS Metal - can I used reduced precision half values for vertex position and color?

Tags: type-conversion, shader, metal, fragment-shader, ios14

I'm trying to experiment with saving memory when rendering a point cloud in Metal. I saw a tutorial which advised using half types (probably on Mac). I would like to try returning half for the vertex position and color when rendering with Metal on iOS, but get the following errors.

I see [Apple says that position and color have to be float here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_a_render_pipeline_to_render_primitives)

**Is there a way to configure Metal rendering to accept half values for position and color?**

```
struct ParticleVertexOut {
    half4 position [[position]]; //Type 'half4' (vector of 4 'half' values) is not valid for attribute 'position'
    half pointSize [[point_size]]; // Type 'half' is not valid for attribute 'point_size'
    half4 color;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, you can't.

Long answer is: if you check out [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), Table 5.3. Attributes for vertex function return type, `[[position]]` can only have `float4` type, same as `[[point_size]]`.

I don't think you'll be able to save any memory bandwidth here as vertex output goes into tiled vertex buffer, at least on Apple GPUs. And unless you have too much geometry and it spills into system memory, all this vertex data stays on chip and it doesn't take up any additional space. There are some talks about it like [Harness Apple GPUs with Metal, WWDC20](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10602/) that go into more detail.

Also, I don't think `half` has enough precision for screen-space coordinates in some cases, but I can be wrong. As for other possible reasons why it has to stay `float`, I'd says it's because of other GPU vendors that might have a more "fixed" vertex pipelines, but again, don't quote me on that.

Comment: Thanks, this adds to my ever-growing list of 3D resources I need to learn :)